# Sending files to zedboard

Tags: ubuntu, neon

I want to run a compiled neon c program on the zedboard. 
Currently i would like to send the compiled file to the zedboard and run the neon c compiled program on the zedboard. I have already compiled the neon program successfully.

I am currently using ubuntu 12.04 vmware.

Things i have tried so far:

- Able to run minicom.
- Tried using minicom to send files through xmodem but fail
- Tried using cat  > /dev/ttyACM0 but return no output.
- Tried to setup the network in minicom and ping but unreachable network.
- Tried ftp,ssh to the board but unreachable network.

What are other options available to be able to send the compiled program to the zedboard and run the neon c compiled program in the zedboard?

I am a beginner user in ubuntu so i am still learning.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it like this, by using XMD for programming zedboard. If I understood your question:
These are steps:

1. run XMD (just type **xmd** in terminal if you have xmd in your path or click on XMD console)
2. If you have some PL design on FPGA part then first program it by using bitstream (if not ignore this one):
   **fpga -f ./path_to_your_bitstream**
3. **connect arm hw**
4. **dow ./path_to_your_executable** (.elf file)